# how to get the type of the base exception of an RPCException in a gRPC client in a MAUI project?

Tags: c#, grpc, maui

I would like to handle the exception when the SSL certificate of the service is not correct.

In this case, the base exception of the RPCException that I get is this: { Interop + AndroidCrypto + SslException}

So to try to handle this exception I am doing this:

```
catch(RPCException ex)
{
    if(ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.Internal)
    {
        if(ex.GetBaseException().GetType() == typeof(???))
    }
}
```

I can't find the SSLException in any namespace. I get this exception when I run an Android application developping with MAUI.

How could I check this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try debugging to see if you can get some specific information about the exception.

Comment: The base exception type is an implementation details and it should only be used for debugging purposes. Your application logic shouldn't make decisions on what the type of the base exception is (unless you're fine with getting your app logic broken when implementation changes).   But if you absolutely need to do this, I'd use debugger as suggested above to detect the exception type that shows up in practice.